# Hive SQL: How to count unique strings by prefix

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Imagine this table

```
text
----
h
he
hel     // All above are prefixes 
helll123   // hel is a prefix of helll123; this is the first occurrence of helll123
helll123   // second helll123 
f
fa
fals
falst0    // fals is a prefix of falst0
```

Below query is pseudo code to demonstrate what I am after

```
SELECT
    unique_by_prefix(text) AS unique_text, // pseudo code
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    my_table
GROUP BY 
    1
```

Should generate the below result

```
unique_text count
helll123       2
falst0         1
```

Basically, we will ignore prefixes and only count unique texts.

Comment: how can you tell which is a prefix and which is a word? there should be some rule.

Comment: I actually not trying to differentiate whether it is a word. I will update the question. I will ignore anything that is a prefix or something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

windowing function 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics

```
select text, 
  lead(text) over ( order by text )  as next_text, 
  lag(text) over ( order by text )  as pre_text 
from my_table;
```

the result will be :

```
text  next_text  pre_text
h      he        NULL
he     hel       h
hel    helll123   he
helll123  helll123   hel 
helll123  f   helll123
f      NULL    helll123
```

then you can compare with these values : if next_text start with text, this record is not the one you want , else get this record.

```
case when instr(next_text, text) = 1 then null else text as text_u_want
```

then remove null and join my_table , you can get text count

Comment: Amazing! Let me try

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this in Hive with one query.

Here is one possibility:

```
select text, count(*)
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.text <> t.text and t2.text like t1.text || '%'
                 )
group by text;
```

Although this captures the logic, I suspect that Hive wants an equality for the correlation clause.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it.

```
            select distinct text into my_table1 from my_table
            alter table my_table1 add sno int identity

            create table my_table2 (text varchar(max), counter int)

            declare @i int = 0
            While (@i < (select COUNT(*) from my_table1))
            Begin
            set @i = @i + 1
            declare @text varchar(max) = (select text FROM my_table1 where sno = @i)
            insert into my_table2 values(
            (select text from my_table1 where sno = @i),
            (select COUNT(*) from my_table1 where text like @text + '%'))
            End

            select A.text, count(*) from my_table A left join my_table2 B on A.text = B.text where B.counter = 1 group by A.text
```